# Scrollview over the fixed image/ImageView Android

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I've gone through numerous links but no luck. When I scroll (vertical) the form up, it hides under the top image. This is a fixed ImageView (height=200dp). The requirement is that when I scroll up the Freight Forwarding Sea form, it should scroll over the image instead below/under the image. I appreciate for prompt solution. Kind Regards
Here is the xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"
    tools:context=".fragments.FFSFragment">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sea_bg">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="200dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners_layout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu_ffs"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_cb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fill_form"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_origin"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_origin"

                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_destination"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_destination"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_commodity"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_commodity"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_weight"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_weight"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_boxes"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_boxes"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_boxe_size"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_boxsize"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choose_images_btn"
                style="@style/AppTheme.RoundButtons"
                android:text="@string/choose_images"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                style="@style/AppTheme.RoundButtons"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/submit"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you give us the current layout code?

Comment: @AimanAlyosofi layout code added.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to do this is by using `MotionLayout`:**

- First, to sure my code going to work with you implement *`MotionLayout` dependency* in your `build.gradle(app)`:

```
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
```

- Change the `RelativeLayout` to `MotionLayout`, and `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DDD"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu_ffs"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_cb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fill_form"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_origin"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_origin"

                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_destination"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_destination"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_commodity"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_commodity"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_weight"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_weight"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_boxes"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_boxes"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_boxe_size"
                style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                android:hint="@string/enter_boxsize"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/choose_images_btn"
                style="@style/AppTheme.RoundButtons"
                android:text="@string/choose_images"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                style="@style/AppTheme.RoundButtons"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/submit"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

- Here focus on the line `app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"`, Android studio going to give you a red error, click at red lamp to show Context Action like in the image below and press at **Create xml resource file**

[image]

- Now go to the file *res\xml\activity_main_scene* and past this code:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <KeyFrameSet></KeyFrameSet>
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/scroll_view"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"></ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

*I hope this helps*, and you can read more about `MotionLayout` its really helpful in this kind of situation

Comment: Perfectly works, thank you @Aiman Alyosofi

Comment: I am glad it help you, Can you make my Answer accepted, please

Answer (score 0):

- Remove Relative layout, use FrameLayout instead
- Another issue is you are providing 200dp paddingTop to Scrollview which stays even when you scroll the view and cause the issue
- You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100877/android-scrollview-with-text-scrolling-over-imageview) too!

  ```
   <FrameLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="@color/light_grey"
       tools:context=".fragments.FFSFragment">
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:src="@drawable/sea_bg" />
       <ScrollView
           android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:scrollbars="vertical">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="vertical">

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="200dp" />
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners_layout">

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/title"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/menu_ffs"
                   android:textSize="25sp"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/text_cb"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/fill_form"
                   android:textSize="16sp"
                   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/et_origin"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                   android:hint="@string/enter_origin"

                   android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/et_destination"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                   android:hint="@string/enter_destination"
                   android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/et_commodity"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                   android:hint="@string/enter_commodity"
                   android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/et_weight"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                   android:hint="@string/enter_weight"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/et_boxes"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                   android:hint="@string/enter_boxes"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/et_boxe_size"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.EditTexts"
                   android:hint="@string/enter_boxsize"
                   android:background="@drawable/rectangle_corners"/>
               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/choose_images_btn"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.RoundButtons"
                   android:text="@string/choose_images"/>
               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                   style="@style/AppTheme.RoundButtons"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                   android:text="@string/submit"/>
           </LinearLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
   </FrameLayout>
  ```

I Hope this answer Helps You!